# Count special characters in range in a function

Tags: excel, vba

This function should count all special hidden characters in selected range.

I got an error. `StrIn = C.Text` didn't work.

```
Function hiddencount(Rng As Range)

Dim C As Range
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim iCh As Integer
Dim StrIn As String
cnt = 0

For Each C In Rng.Cells
    C.Value = StrIn

    If Not C.HasFormula Then
        For iCh = 1 To Len(StrIn)
            If Asc(Mid(StrIn, iCh, 1)) < 32 Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next iCh
    Else
    End If
Next C

hiddencount = cnt

End Function
```

Comment: Can you explain what your function should do please.

Comment: Shouldn't `C.Value = StrIn` be reversed? `StrIn = C.Value`. Otherwise you are setting `C` to nothing

Comment: `C.Value = StrIn` should be `StrIn = C.Text `

Comment: function should count all special hidden characters in selected range. But I still got error. StrIn = C.Text didnt work

Comment: Further to what @urdearboy has stated, a worksheet UDF will not even let you set the value of any cell other than the one the UDF resides in, so there's that problem on top of the reversed var assignment.

Comment: I am sorry its working now. YOu were right...just needed to be reversed. Thak u guys

Comment: Simply switching to StrIn = C.Text worked for me.

Comment: Wanna call this a typo or should @urdearboy type out a quick answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, change `C.Value = StrIn` to `StrIn = C.Text`

---

You really do not need this variable though. It just creates more code to read through later. Why not just use `C.Text` so it is clear what is being analyzed? Also, if you do not plan on acting on the `Else` statement, you can just remove it.

```
Function hiddencount(Rng As Range)

Dim C As Range, cnt As Integer, iCh As Integer

For Each C In Rng.Cells
    If Not C.HasFormula Then
        For iCh = 1 To Len(C.Text)
            If Asc(Mid(C.Text, iCh, 1)) < 32 Then cnt = cnt + 1
        Next iCh
    End If
Next C

hiddencount = cnt

End Function
```

Comment: @MartinLauf, hover under the answer score and click the checkmark to acknowledge this as the answer.